# How to apply .ClearOutline On QueryTable?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm putting outlines on a table that gets data from Power Query through VBA based on data in the table itself.

```vb
ActiveSheet.Rows(2).Cells(7).Activate ' Set the row containing the OutlineLevel value to be active
Dim RowNumber As Integer ' Counter for the row we're on
For RowNumber = 2 To ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row ' Go from the first data row to the last row containing data in the first cell of the sheet
    ActiveCell.EntireRow.OutlineLevel = CInt(ActiveCell.Value) ' Set the outline level
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate ' Go to the next row in the sheet
Next RowNumber
```

That works as long as I clear the outline manually first. However, when I clear all the outlines first by executing:

```
ActiveSheet.Rows().ClearOutline
```

I get

> Run-time error '1004': ClearOutline method of Range class failed

I tried clearing the outline for all the rows by running:

```
ActiveSheet.Rows().OutlineLevel = 1
```

That causes a 30-150ms delay when I set `.OutlineLevel`, and for 150K rows, that's going to cause issues.

Answer (score 0):

> ActiveSheet.Rows().ClearOutline

With `.Rows().` you are getting that error because you are not only trying to ungroup the rows which have the grouping but also rest of the rows in the worksheet which are not grouped and hence you are getting the error.

Encase that line with OERN and try again

```
On Error Resume Next
ActiveSheet.Rows().ClearOutline
On Error GoTo 0
```

Or ensure that you find the relevant rows which are grouped and then ungroup only those rows. Something like this (**Untested**)

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long

Set ws = Sheet1

With ws
    lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    For i = 1 To lRow
        If .Rows(i).OutlineLevel > 1 Then
            If rng Is Nothing Then
                Set rng = Rows(i)
            Else
                Set rng = Union(rng, Rows(i))
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End With

If Not rng Is Nothing Then rng.ClearOutline
```