# Ungroup method of Range class failed on Power Query table

Tags: excel, vba

Attempting to group rows and columns on a sheet ("180 Day") with a query table on it and it's triggering a run time 1004 error citing "Ungroup method of Range class failed".  I can run this script on static tables without err and my partner can even get this to execute on his machine but he does not have Power Query active on his system.  Any wisdom on how this can be modified or with what's actually causing the issue?

Desired effect and code below.

[image]

```
Sub update_default_row_column_groupings180()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lrow As Long, i As Long
    Dim rng As Range

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("180 Day")

    On Error GoTo err_exit
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    On Error Resume Next
    For i = 1 To 8
        ws.Rows.Ungroup
        ws.Columns.Ungroup
    Next i
    On Error GoTo err_exit

    ws.Rows.Hidden = False
    ws.Columns.Hidden = False

    ws.Cells.Columns("E:F").Group
    ws.Cells.Columns("I:J").Group
    ws.Cells.Columns("M").Group
    ws.Cells.Columns("Q:R").Group

    group_rows_hierarchy_level ws, hierarchy_level:="region", group_column:=2, start_row:=6
    group_rows_hierarchy_level ws, hierarchy_level:="division", group_column:=2, start_row:=5

err_exit:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

End Sub

Sub group_rows_hierarchy_level(ByVal ws As Worksheet, hierarchy_level As String, group_column As Long, start_row As Long)

    'groups rows between instances of 'hierarchy_level' in 'group_column'

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim group_ranges As Scripting.Dictionary

    Set group_ranges = New Scripting.Dictionary

    last_row = ws.Cells(ws.Cells.Rows.Count, group_column).End(xlUp).Row

    group_start_row = 0
    group_end_row = 0

    For i = start_row To last_row

        previous_val = ws.Cells(i - 1, group_column).Value
        current_val = ws.Cells(i, group_column).Value


        If LCase(current_val) = LCase(hierarchy_level) Then

            If group_start_row = 0 Then
            
                group_start_row = i + 1
                
            ElseIf group_end_row = 0 Then
            
                If LCase(previous_val) = "division" And LCase(hierarchy_level) = "region" Then
                    group_end_row = i - 2
                Else
                    group_end_row = i - 1
                End If
                Rows("" & group_start_row & ":" & group_end_row).Group
                group_start_row = i + 1
                group_end_row = 0
                
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    ws.Rows("" & group_start_row & ":" & last_row).Group

    On Error Resume Next
    With ws.Outline
         SummaryRow = xlAbove
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

End Sub

Sub group_columns(ws As Worksheet, col_groups As Variant)
    
    For Each col_group In col_groups

        ws.Cells.Columns(col_group).Group
    Next col_group

End Sub
Sub group_rows(ws As Worksheet, row_groups As Variant)

    For Each row_group In row_groups
        ws.Cells.Rows(row_group).Group
    Next row_group

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there wasn't grouped row, `ws.Rows.Ungroup` raises run-time error 1004. `ws.Columns.Ungroup` is same.

Running the `Ungroup` method repeatedly (for example in a loop) can result in error 1004 once there isn't grouped row.

```
    For i = 1 To 8
        ws.Rows.Ungroup
        ws.Columns.Ungroup
    Next i
```

There is a tidy approach to clear all outline all at once.

**Note:** `ClearOutline` raises run-time error 1004 if there is Power Query table on worksheet. (Tested with Excel 365)

```vb
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("180 Day")
    With ws.Cells
        .ClearOutline
        .EntireRow.Hidden = False
        .EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    End With
```

Microsoft reference document:

> [Range.ClearOutline method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.clearoutline?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

---

***UPDATE:***

I found a workaround solution. Maybe it is not as efficient as bulit-in `ClearOutline` method. But it's reliable with `power query table`. The code is tested with Excel 365.

```vb
Sub Demo()
    Dim c As Range, dataRng As Range
    Set dataRng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange ' Update sheet as needed
    For Each c In dataRng.EntireRow
        If c.OutlineLevel > 1 Then c.OutlineLevel = 1
    Next
    For Each c In dataRng.EntireColumn
        If c.OutlineLevel > 1 Then c.OutlineLevel = 1
    Next
    ' Show all rows and columns
    With ActiveSheet.Cells
        .EntireRow.Hidden = False
        .EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Microsoft reference document:

> [Range.OutlineLevel property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.outlinelevel?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

Comment: Thank you for the response.  Unfortunately, I now get a 1004 Run-time error that reads ClearOutline method of range class failed.  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65334504/how-to-apply-clearoutline-on-querytable) This link seems to somewhat explain the issue however, I'd need it to loop through the rows down to lrow UNTIL all levels are cleared, not just the first.

Comment: Is `Worksheets("180 Day")` protected? Please share the full message on run-tim error pop-up window.

Comment: It is not protected... the error is Run-time error '1004': ClearOutline method of Range class failed

That's all that it reads.

Comment: If the sheets is exist in your workbook, the code shouldn't raise error no matter there is grouped rows/columns or not. Please replace the first line with `Set ws = ActiveSheet` to test the code of `ClearOutline`.

Comment: The sheet definitely exists, the ActiveSheet setting still fires the same error.  There's something about the code, grouping and the PowerQuery table that exists on the sheet that's triggering the error.  I know there has to be a work around, I just don't know what it is.  The link I posted in my first comment sort of explains what's occurring but I'm unsure of how to fix it.

Comment: I have posted a walkaround solution. Hope it's helpful for you.

Comment: Bruh, incredible job!  Thank you!